# jQuery UI Dialog with jqGrid loaded by AJAX is not closing

Tags: jquery-ui, jqgrid

I have a jqGrid loaded by AJAX inside a jQuery UI Dialog. Everything is working fine, except the Dialog which is not closing. When I click in both buttons, it reaches the alerts, but the Dialog is not being closed.

```
buttons: {
    'Confirm': function() {
        alert('OK Confirm');
        $('#test-grid').dialog('close');
    },
    'Cancelar': function() {
        alert('OK Cancel');
        $(this).dialog('close');
    }
}
```

I've tried with `$('#test-grid').dialog('close')` and `$(this).dialog('close')`, but no one works. If I remove the jqGrid loaded by AJAX, everything works fine. 
The error console on Firefox and Chrome is empty.

I'm loading the jqGrid page with:

```
$('#test-grid').load('/grid').dialog('open');
```

Can anyone help me?

**UPDATE**

I've tried to load a simple HTML snippet using AJAX and the problem persists.

Comment: Can you show us the code you use to create the actual grid?

Comment: Yes, I can, but any content loaded using AJAX causes this problem, not only jqGrid.

Comment: Hmmm... Have you tried using `load` to retrieve data into a child element of `test-grid` instead of loading that element directly?

Comment: No problem, I'm glad you got it working! :) I just re-posted the comment as an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the call to `load` is interfering with the call to open the dialog. You can fix this by loading the AJAX content into a child element of `test-grid`. For example:

```
 $('#test-grid-child').load('/grid');
 $('#test-grid').dialog('open');
```

---

**Update**

I just read the [docs for `load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) and gave this a bit more thought. What is happening is that when the code `$('#test-grid').load('/grid').dialog('open');` is executed, an AJAX request is started and the dialog is created immediately. But once the `load`'s AJAX request finishes, jQuery comes back and overwrites the contents of `#test-grid`. This explains why the dialog could not be closed, because the underlying markup is modified out from underneath the dialog object.

Retrieving data to a child element eliminates this problem since `load` and `dialog` each now manipulates a different section of the DOM.

Note that if the AJAX request takes a long time to complete, you might want to consider implementing a `complete` function to give feedback to the user - maybe by displaying a spinner until the data is ready. For example:

```
$('#test-grid-child').load('ajax/test.html', function() {
  alert('Load was performed.'); // Perform any necessary UI action here
});
```

Anyway, more information than you probably needed, but I just wanted to update this question while it was still fresh in my mind...